# WKWebView's (beta) takeSnapshot method, how to implement?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, xcode9-beta

I noticed the `WKWebView` documentation now lists a method called [`takeSnapshot`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/2873260-takesnapshot) that is supported by iOS 11 and macOS 10.13 and above (Xcode 9 beta).

Has anyone played around with yet or implemented?  I'm trying to get it working in a playground but I'm not sure where to start?  Is this a method on a `WKWebView`?

My code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import WebKit



let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height:600)
let web = WKWebView(frame: frame)
let rq = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://apple.com")! as URL)
web.load(rq)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = web
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

//Take snapshot?
```

Comment: Agree with OOPer, this is definitely a bug: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5066137213599744

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I tested, the method `takeSnapshot(with:completionHandler:)` actually exists as an instance method and works as expected.

Just that it's a little hard to use it.

The method declares its first parameter as `WKSnapshotConfiguration?`, but the class `WKSnapshotConfiguration` is not imported with `import WebKit`. You can pass `nil` to the parameter, but to use the method, you need to import the type `WKSnapshotConfiguration`. And I could not have found any dependent submodules to import `WKSnapshotConfiguration`.

So, if you want to play with this new feature, you need to create an App project with bridging-header.
(If you know how to use bridging-header in the Playground, you may test this feature in it. But I do not know if you can or how.)

{ProjectName}-Bridging-Header.h:

```
@import CoreGraphics;
#import <WebKit/WKSnapshotConfiguration.h>
```

And an example of ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://apple.com")!)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        webView.takeSnapshot(with: nil) {image, error in
            if let image = image {
                self.imageView.image = image
                print("Got snapshot")
            } else {
                print("Failed taking snapshot: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "--")")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

(Place a `WKWebView`, a `UIImageView` and a `UIButton` on a View.)

---

One more, this seems to be a bug of WebKit framework, you should better send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to Apple.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.  Nice find with `<WebKit/WKSnapshotConfiguration.h>`, although the compiler complains about a missing WebKit submodule.  Also you might want to remove the `WKSnapshotConfiguration()` as the are no public initializers for it.

Comment: @JAL, thanks. `WKSnapshotConfiguration()` is a ruin of something I was testing, forgotten to remove it. And as this seems to be a bug, to test the feature, we may need to ignore some warnings.

Comment: You can ignore the warning with `#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincomplete-umbrella"
#import <WebKit/WKSnapshotConfiguration.h>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop`

Comment: How does this work in Objective-C?